# How do I make this to where people only have to click once and then the other animations follow suite?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, css-animations

How do I make this to where people only have to click once and then the other animations follow suite? So essentially they click the envelope but then from there it just follows all animations and then ends. Maybe a second between each animation.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  // Add Flip Envelope Event Handler
  document.getElementById('envelope_front').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('envelope_front').classList.toggle('flipped');
    document.getElementById('envelope_back').classList.toggle('flipped');
  }

  // Add Open Envelope Event Handler
  document.getElementById('flap_outside').onclick = function() {

    document.getElementById('flap_outside').classList.toggle('open');
    document.getElementById('flap_inside').classList.toggle('open');

    // Add Remove Card Event Handler
    // This is added after "Open Envelope" so that card can't be removed
    // until the envelope has been opened
    document.getElementById('envelope_back_outside').onclick = function() {
      document.getElementById('card').classList.toggle('removed');
      return false;
    }

    return false;
  }

  // Open Card
  document.getElementById('card').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('card_outside_front').classList.toggle('open');
    document.getElementById('card_inside_top').classList.toggle('open');
    return false;
  }

}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #666;
  font-family: Futura, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000;
}

#envelope {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 400px auto 0 auto;
}

#envelope_front {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* This seems required for Chrome */
  background: #FFF url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') 0px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(10px);
}

#envelope_front.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}

#envelope_back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #FFF url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') -600px -400px;
  -webkit-transition: all 4s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(3px);
}

#envelope_back.flipped {
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
}

#flap_outside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') -600px -200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0) translateZ(3px);
}

#flap_outside.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg) translateZ(0);
}

#flap_inside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
  background: transparent url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') -602px 0px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateY(-200px) translateZ(3px);
}

#flap_inside.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateY(-200px) translateZ(0);
}

#envelope_back_outside {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') 0px -400px;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(2px);
}

#card {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 580px;
  height: 380px;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(1px);
}

#card.removed {
  -webkit-animation-name: remove-card;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 0;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#card_outside_front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #FFF url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') -1809px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(0px);
}

#card_outside_front.open {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

#card_inside_top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 4px #083251;
  background: #FFF url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') -1210px -10px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 380px;
  /* 379 is used instead of 380 to prevent any gap between the two layers (visible in Safari) */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(-379px) rotateX(-180deg);
}

#card_inside_top.open {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px) translateY(-379px) rotateX(0deg);
}

#card_inside_bottom {
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 4px #222c36;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  /* Hide behind #card_outside_front and #card_inside_top */
  background: #FFF url('http://www.crosshudson.tv/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/NW-01-1.png') -1217px 390px;
}


/* Animation Keyframes for removing the card */

@-webkit-keyframes remove-card {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateZ(1px);
  }
  33% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px) translateZ(1px);
  }
  67% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-400px) translateZ(3px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px) translateZ(3px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="envelope">
  <div id="envelope_front"></div>
  <div id="envelope_back">
    <div id="flap_outside"></div>
    <div id="flap_inside"></div>
    <div id="envelope_back_outside"></div>
    <div id="card">
      <div id="card_outside_front"></div>
      <div id="card_inside_top"></div>
      <div id="card_inside_bottom"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>Click to Open - Webkit Browser Required</p>
```

Comment: elements emit animation events, like [animationend](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/animationend) etc - use them wisely

Comment: Another option is to use CSS animations: https://devdocs.io/css/animation